# Auth driver [passport] for guard [api] is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7 and passport for oauth2. When I am trying to access the /api/user route with postman I am getting this error.

Comment: What library are you using? did you use the default in laravel or used something else?

Comment: Yes, I am using the default passport library only.

Comment: you ran `composer require laravel/passport` right?

Comment: yes, requesting and getting access tokens is working fine. But when trying access a resource with api gaurd I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Actually I am using Swoole server rather than the php-fpm. I have to add the Passport class to the provides array in swoole configuration file swoole_http.php .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't setup your guard.

Please check you guard driver setup into `config/auth.php` first.

Comment: `'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],`

Comment: that is the code in my auth.php file. I have added the passport driver to the api gaurd.

Answer (score 0):

Passport includes an [authentication guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#adding-custom-guards) that will validate access tokens on incoming requests. Once you have configured the api guard to use the passport driver, you only need to specify the auth:api middleware on any routes that require a valid access token:

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their access token as a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header of their request. For example, when using the Guzzle HTTP library:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar situation, you need to configure your **driver** to **passport** inside your **config/auth.php** file.
 *For my case, I found a dummy command "passportphp artisan passport:keys* instead of "passport""

```
        'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
```

Next check carefully your headers and be sure you set

**Authorization** : "Bearer + token" and  **Accept** to **Application/json**

Answer (score 0):

this problem also occurs if you capitalize "passport" in config/auth.php :

correct :

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
```

wrong :

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'Passport',
```

notice that first letter of passport should not be capitalized !

Answer (score 0):

It's a stupid solution, but I just had the same situation, so maybe, someone is going to find this useful.

I was using `php artisan clear-compiled` command in my deployment script which cleared generated passport keys, so whenever I was calling any route that's under auth middleware, I was getting this error.

So, the solution is to just call `php artisan passport:install` command again and everything is going to be working normally.